# Multiples Inner Join in Odata

Tags: sql, asp.net-web-api, odata

im new using Odata and i´m trying to figure out how to get the equivalent of:

```
SELECT s.xx, s.yy FROM products p 
INNER JOIN Company c on p.idcompany = c.idcompany
INNER JOIN companystore cs on c.idcompany = cs.idcompany 
INNER JOIN store s on cs.idstore = s.idstore
```

How would this url be constructed? I tried a lot of things but the closest was this one, but i lack to get the last Inner Join.

`localhost:6569/product(10)/company/?$expand=companyStore`

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement should return what you are looking for:

> localhost:6569/product(10)/company/?$expand=companyStore/store

[Here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata01/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata01-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc395267179) is a link to some further OData documentation.